# How do I find corners of a paper when there are printed corners/lines on paper itself?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection, corner-detection

I'm using openCV in Python to find the corners of a sheet of paper to unwarp it.

```
img = cv2.imread(images[i])

        corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),4,.01,1000,useHarrisDetector=True,k=.04)
        corners = np.float32(corners)
        print(corners)
        ratio = 1.6
        cardH = math.sqrt((corners[2][0][0] - corners[1][0][0]) * (corners[2][0][0] - corners[1][0][0]) + (corners[2][0][1] - corners[1][0][1]) * (
                    corners[2][0][1] - corners[1][0][1]))
        cardW = ratio * cardH;
        pts2 = np.float32(
            [[corners[0][0][0], corners[0][0][1]], [corners[0][0][0] + cardW, corners[0][0][1]], [corners[0][0][0] + cardW, corners[0][0][1] + cardH],
             [corners[0][0][0], corners[0][0][1] + cardH]])

        M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(corners, pts2)

        offsetSize = 500
        transformed = np.zeros((int(cardW + offsetSize), int(cardH + offsetSize)), dtype=np.uint8);
        dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, transformed.shape)
```

Before:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdUqG.jpg

After:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkEh6.jpg

As you can see with these images, they're detecting edges inside the paper itself, rather than the corner of the paper. Should I consider using a different algorithm entirely? I'm quite lost.

I've tried increasing the minimum euclidean distance to 1000, but that really didn't do anything.

***Please note, this no one's real information, this is a fake dataset found on Kaggle.***

The kaggle dataset can be found https://www.kaggle.com/mcvishnu1/fake-w2-us-tax-form-dataset

Comment: Are those Social Security numbers real? If so I don't think you should post those photos.

Comment: @AaronJones No, this is a fake procured dataset from Kaggle. If you want a link it's right here https://www.kaggle.com/mcvishnu1/fake-w2-us-tax-form-dataset

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make sure. That's good though.

Comment: You probably are not getting the proper corners. Perhaps draw the found corners on the input to see where they are.  I would suggest that you threshold the image to extract the page from the background, then apply morphology to remove the text and find contours to eliminate any other extraneous region. Then find the corners. Or alternately, use approxPolyDP  to the contour perimeter to get a 4-sided polygon and get its vertices.

Comment: Do you have your conjugate corners matched properly between the input and rectified image? You may need to sort your found corner in the input page.

Comment: For sorting corners in clockwise direction, see https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/21/ordering-coordinates-clockwise-with-python-and-opencv/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

*Note that the found corners are listed counter-clockwise from the top-most corner.*

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Gaussian blur
- Otsu threshold
- Morphology open/close to clean up the threshold
- Get largest contour
- Approximate a polygon from the contour
- Get the corners
- Draw the polygon on the input
- Compute side lengths
- Compute output corresponding corners
- Get perspective transformation matrix from corresponding corner points
- Warp the input image according to the matrix
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("efile.jpg")

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur image
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)

# do otsu threshold on gray image
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology
kernel = np.ones((7,7), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
area_thresh = 0
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > area_thresh:
        area_thresh = area
        big_contour = c

# draw white filled largest contour on black just as a check to see it got the correct region
page = np.zeros_like(img)
cv2.drawContours(page, [big_contour], 0, (255,255,255), -1)

# get perimeter and approximate a polygon
peri = cv2.arcLength(big_contour, True)
corners = cv2.approxPolyDP(big_contour, 0.04 * peri, True)

# draw polygon on input image from detected corners
polygon = img.copy()
cv2.polylines(polygon, [corners], True, (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
# Alternate: cv2.drawContours(page,[corners],0,(0,0,255),1)

# print the number of found corners and the corner coordinates
# They seem to be listed counter-clockwise from the top most corner
print(len(corners))
print(corners)

# for simplicity get average of top/bottom side widths and average of left/right side heights
# note: probably better to get average of horizontal lengths and of vertical lengths
width = 0.5*( (corners[0][0][0] - corners[1][0][0]) + (corners[3][0][0] - corners[2][0][0]) )
height = 0.5*( (corners[2][0][1] - corners[1][0][1]) + (corners[3][0][1] - corners[0][0][1]) )
width = np.int0(width)
height = np.int0(height)

# reformat input corners to x,y list
icorners = []
for corner in corners:
    pt = [ corner[0][0],corner[0][1] ]
    icorners.append(pt)
icorners = np.float32(icorners)

# get corresponding output corners from width and height
ocorners = [ [width,0], [0,0], [0,height], [width,height] ]
ocorners = np.float32(ocorners)

# get perspective tranformation matrix
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(icorners, ocorners)

# do perspective 
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (width, height))

# write results
cv2.imwrite("efile_thresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("efile_morph.jpg", morph)
cv2.imwrite("efile_polygon.jpg", polygon)
cv2.imwrite("efile_warped.jpg", warped)

# display it
cv2.imshow("efile_thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("efile_morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("efile_page", page)
cv2.imshow("efile_polygon", polygon)
cv2.imshow("efile_warped", warped)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Morphology cleaned image:

[image]

Polygon drawn on input:

[image]

Extracted Corners (counterclockwise from top right corner)

```
4

[[[693  67]]
 [[ 23  85]]
 [[ 62 924]]
 [[698 918]]]
```

Warped Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I looked at all your lines of code, line by line and adapted some parameters for images that weren't quite getting what I wanted.

Comment: Edit it as you desire.